# Dependency error messages when running luigi pipeline

Tags: python, luigi

Im trying to create a pipeline that starts off with a class that separates one file into multiple csvs based on the state a user is in, then looks at the files created representing the different states and tries to determine whether a user moved from one state to another returning a 1 if the user did and 0 if s/he did not, fits these 'probabilities' using a gaussian kde, saves this as a pickle and then gets samples from the pickle and saves them as csvs.

I am using luigi to build this pipeline but keep encountering error messages when trying to run my code. The pipeline seems to fail when running the state_to_state class.

Here is the code I have written:

separate_csv.py:

```
import luigi
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import state_to_state_transitions2 as sst
class data_filter(luigi.Task):
    file = pd.read_csv('/Users/emmanuels/Desktop/Attribution/finalcleanattributiondata.csv')
    actions = file.state.unique()
    def run(self):
        for current in self.actions:
            filter_file = self.file.loc[self.file.state.str.contains(current,na=False)]
            filter_file.to_csv('/Users/emmanuels/Documents/AttributionData/Data/'+str(current)+'.csv')
    def requires(self):
        return []
    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('/Users/emmanuels/Documents/AttributionData/Data/'+str(self.actions)+'.csv')
```

state_to_state_transitions2;

```
import luigi
import pandas as pd
import separate_csv
class state_to_state(luigi.Task):
    first_file = luigi.Parameter()
    second_file = luigi.Parameter()
    def run(self):
        #iterate through states and find probability of anonymous id existing in next state
        first = pd.read_csv(self.first_file)
        second = pd.read_csv(self.second_file)
        first['probability'] = first.anonymous_id.isin(second.anonymous_id).astype(int)
        #save anonymous id along with probability (1,0) of whether or not it exists in the next state
        first[['anonymous_id','probability']].to_csv('/Users/emmanuels/Documents/AttributionData/Data/Probabilities/'+str(self.first_file.split('/')[6][:-4]+'to'+self.second_file.split('/')[7][:-4]+'.csv'))
    def requires(self):
        return separate_csv.data_filter()
    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('/Users/emmanuels/Documents/AttributionData/Data/Probabilities/'+str(self.first_file.split('/')[6][:-4]+'to'+self.second_file.split('/')[6][:-4]+'.csv'))
```

gaussian_kdefit;

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle
from scipy import stats
import luigi
import state_to_state_transitions2 as sst
class save_distributions(luigi.Task):
    file_tag = luigi.Parameter()
    path = '/Users/emmanuels/Documents/AttributionData/Data/Probabilities/'
    def run(self):
        data = pd.read_csv(path+self.file_tag)
        kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(data['probability'])
        #we fit the distribution and save as a pickle
        pickle.dump(kernel,open('/Users/emmanuels/Documents/AttributionData/Data/Probabilities/'+str(self.file_tag)+'probabs'+'.pck','wb'))
    def requires(self):
        files = ['Session.csv','lead.csv','opportunity.csv','complete.csv']
        task_list = []
        for i in range(1,len(files)):
            one = self.path+str(files[i-1])
            two = self.path+str(files[i])
            task_list.append(sst.state_to_state(first_file=one,second_file=two))
        return task_list
    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('/Users/emmanuels/Documents/AttributionData/Data/Probabilities/'+str(self.file_tag)+'probabs'+'.pck')
```

get_samples:

```
import pandas as pd
import luigi
import gaussian_kdefit as gkde
#takes n samples and saves sample in csv
class sample_output(luigi.Task):
    file_tag = luigi.Parameter()
    size = luigi.Parameter()
    def run(self):
        kernel = pd.read_pickle('/Users/emmanuels/Documents/AttributionData/Data/Probabilities/'+str(self.file_tag)+'probabs'+'.pck')
        kernel = kernel.resample(int(self.size))
        pd.DataFrame(kernel).transpose().to_csv('/Users/emmanuels/Documents/AttributionData/Data/Probabilities/'+str(self.file_tag)+'+sampleprobabs'+'.csv')
    def requires(self):
        files = ['Sessiontolead.csv', 'leadtoopportunity.csv', 'opportunitytocomplete.csv']
        return [gkde.save_distributions(file_tag=file) for file in files]
    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('/Users/emmanuels/Documents/AttributionData/Data/Probabilities/'+str(self.file_tag)+'+sampleprobabs'+'.csv')
```

and my wrapper class:

```
import get_samples as getsamps
import pandas as pd
import luigi
class wrapper(luigi.WrapperTask):
    def requires(self):
        file_tag = ['Sessiontolead', 'leadtoopportunity', 'opportunitytocomplete']
        task_list = []
        size = 10
        for i in range(0,len(file_tag)):
            for k in range(1,size):
                task_list.append(getsamps.sample_output(file_tag=file_tag[i],size=size))
        return task_list
    def run(self):
        print('Wrapper ran')
        pd.DataFrame().to_csv('/Users/emmanuels/Documents/AttributionData/Data/wrangler1.csv')
    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget('/Users/emmanuels/Documents/AttributionData/Data/wrangler1.csv')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    luigi.build([wrapper()],workers=8,local_scheduler=True)
```

Here is a sample of the final clean attribution file:

```
{'Unnamed: 0': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4},
 'uniques': {0: '2019-06-18 09:00:000000a6a0-00bc-475f-a9e5-9dcbb4309e78https://signup.yoc.com/signup/v1/https://signup.yoc.com/signup/v1/step/businessDetails/',
  1: '2019-06-18 09:00:000000a6a0-00bc-475f-a9e5-9dcbb4309e78https://signup.yoc.com/signup/v1/https://signup.yoc.com/signup/v1/step/businessDetails/',
  2: '2019-06-18 09:00:000000a6a0-00bc-475f-a9e5-9dcbb4309e78https://signup.yoc.com/signup/v1/https://signup.yoc.com/signup/v1/step/userDetails/',
  3: '2018-05-17 20:00:000000c924-5959-4e2d-8757-0d10f96ca462http://m.facebook.com/https://www.yoc.com/signup/',
  4: '2019-02-24 16:00:000002269a-1e39-4cdf-a43e-cecf0a277c1chttps://signup.yoc.com/continue/1551024250465-dfd0e1d5-b76a-4bfa-bc29-9fcf5ef6b91c'},
 'anonymous_id': {0: '0000a6a0-00bc-475f-a9e5-9dcbb4309e78',
  1: '0000a6a0-00bc-475f-a9e5-9dcbb4309e78',
  2: '0000a6a0-00bc-475f-a9e5-9dcbb4309e78',
  3: '0000c924-5959-4e2d-8757-0d10f96ca462',
  4: '0002269a-1e39-4cdf-a43e-cecf0a277c1c'},
 'user_id': {0: '1560849071242-a19cdf50-ceec-41a0-ab51-ba9a45c8cda9',
  1: '1560849071242-a19cdf50-ceec-41a0-ab51-ba9a45c8cda9',
  2: '1560849071242-a19cdf50-ceec-41a0-ab51-ba9a45c8cda9',
  3: nan,
  4: nan},
 'ts': {0: '2019-06-18 09:11:14.409000',
  1: '2019-06-18 09:11:15.028000',
  2: '2019-06-18 09:12:03.118000',
  3: '2018-05-17 20:31:32.203000',
  4: '2019-02-24 16:08:32.661000'},
 'url': {0: 'https://signup.yoc.com/signup/v1/step/businessDetails/',
  1: 'https://signup.yoc.com/signup/v1/step/businessDetails/',
  2: 'https://signup.yoc.com/signup/v1/step/userDetails/',
  3: 'https://www.yoc.com/signup/',
  4: 'https://signup.yoc.com/continue/1551024250465-dfd0e1d5-b76a-4bfa-bc29-9fcf5ef6b91c'},
 'path': {0: '/za/signup/v1/step/businessDetails/',
  1: '/za/signup/v1/step/businessDetails/',
  2: '/za/signup/v1/step/userDetails/',
  3: '/za/signup/',
  4: '/continue/1551024250465-dfd0e1d5-b76a-4bfa-bc29-9fcf5ef6b91c'},
 'referrer_domain': {0: 'signup.yoc.com',
  1: 'signup.yoc.com',
  2: 'signup.yoc.com',
  3: 'm.facebook.com',
  4: nan},
 'utm_campaign': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 'utm_content': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 'utm_medium': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan},
 'utm_source': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: 'facebook', 4: nan},
 'user_agent': {0: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36',
  1: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36',
  2: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36',
  3: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.0.0; SM-G965F Build/R16NW; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/66.0.3359.158 Mobile Safari/537.36 [FB_IAB/FB4A;FBAV/172.0.0.66.93;]',
  4: 'Opera/9.80 (Android; Opera Mini/38.1.2254/131.123; U; en) Presto/2.12.423 Version/12.16'},
 'rank': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 1, 4: 1},
 'state': {0: 'lead',
  1: 'lead',
  2: 'opportunity',
  3: 'Session',
  4: 'opportunity'}}
```

Here is the traceback I am getting:

```
Scheduled 9 tasks of which:
* 1 ran successfully:
    - 1 data_filter(file=/Users/emmanuels/Desktop/Attribution/finalcleanattributiondata.csv)
* 1 failed:
    - 1 state_to_state(first_file=/Users/emmanuels/Documents/AttributionData/Data/Session.csv, second_file=/Users/emmanuels/Documents/AttributionData/Data/lead.csv)
* 7 were left pending, among these:
    * 7 had failed dependencies:
        - 3 sample_output(file_tag=Sessiontolead, size=10) ...
        - 3 save_distributions(file_tag=Sessiontolead.csv,leadtoopportunity.csv,opportunitytocomplete.csv)
        - 1 wrapper()
```

....

```
INFO: [pid 45306] Worker Worker(salt=271561701, workers=1, host=Emmanuels-MacBook-Pro.local, username=emmanuels, pid=45306) running   state_to_state(first_file=/Users/emmanuels/Documents/AttributionData/Data/Session.csv, second_file=/Users/emmanuels/Documents/AttributionData/Data/lead.csv)
WARNING: Using wildcards in path /Users/emmanuels/Documents/AttributionData/Data/['lead' 'opportunity' 'Session' 'complete'].csv might lead to processing of an incomplete dataset; override exists() to suppress the warning.
ERROR: [pid 45306] Worker Worker(salt=271561701, workers=1, host=Emmanuels-MacBook-Pro.local, username=emmanuels, pid=45306) failed    state_to_state(first_file=/Users/emmanuels/Documents/AttributionData/Data/Session.csv, second_file=/Users/emmanuels/Documents/AttributionData/Data/lead.csv)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/emmanuels/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/luigi/worker.py", line 175, in run
    raise RuntimeError('Unfulfilled %s at run time: %s' % (deps, ', '.join(missing)))
RuntimeError: Unfulfilled dependency at run time: data_filter__Users_emmanuels_c87d333278
DEBUG: 1 running tasks, waiting for next task to finish
INFO: Informed scheduler that task   state_to_state__Users_emmanuels__Users_emmanuels_c95a12621e   has status   FAILED
```

Comment: Can you provide the actual errors you are receiving? Or a better description of them?

Comment: @iHowell I tried adding more detail regarding the error message I am getting

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your updates, I noticed that your first task doesn't actually have any parameters. You just have a couple of objects. You shouldn't run `pd.read_csv` inside of variable declaration. Instead, you should have it in the `run` method (unless you need to require things based off the data, then also read it in the `requires` method). Instead, change `file` to be a `luigi.Parameter` with a `default` value. Also, it's hard to tell what `self.actions` is supposed to be. Parameters (and self variables) should be primitives or serializable to primitives.

Further, you have a recursive import, which might be messing things up. In your `separate_csv` you import `state_to_state_transition2` and vice-versa.

Honestly, there's so much here, it could be a lot of things. I would work on stripping down your workflow and working on components one at a time. In addition, you could use `luigi`'s input/output methods to better transfer data along your pipeline.

Prev issue that could still make things a problem:

Your issue could be that you aren't using Luigi's internal atomic file system. Instead of opening the file in `state_to_state_transision2`:

```
class state_to_state(luigi.Task):
    def run(self):
        ...
        first[['anonymous_id','probability']].to_csv(...)
```

Instead of writing to it yourself, you should open the file with luigi's output command:

```
class state_to_state(luigi.Task):
    def run(self):
        ...
        with self.output().open('w') as out_csv:
            out_csv.write(first[['anonymous_id','probability']].to_csv())
```

By not using the atomic filesystem, the file will be created even if you just write in error to it. This signals to luigi that the task is completed, due to the file's existence.